# Proving Multivariate Version of Mean Value Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

Given a convex open set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^k$, $f:S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is a differentiable map and $\forall x \in S.\|f'(x)\| \leq M.$ I am trying to prove $\forall p,q \in S,\|f(p)-f(q)\| \leq M\|p-q\|.$ Given this is a sort of multivariable version of the Mean Value Theorem, I am wondering if we can begin with a sort of multivariate version of Rolle's Theorem?

Comment: What do you mean by $f'$ when $m > 1$?

Comment: If your norm is euclidean, consider the scalar function $g(t) = u^T f(p + t(q-p))$ for $t\in[0,1]$ where $u = (f(p) - f(q)) / \| f(p) - f(q) \|$.